# How can I ignore exception in php

Tags: php, exception, cakephp-2.0

I am doing this:

```
try
{
    $result=100/0;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $result=0;
}
```

I am getting Division by Zero exception:

> Warning: Division by zero

but I want to make the result zero when exception occurs. How can I do it. Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing to ask as you are doing fine.

Comment: Generally, you should avoid ignoring such exceptions, just check you're not dividing by 0 first. Exceptions are for exceptional use cases.

Comment: You are getting a warning not an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than catching the exception (although as noted by tlenss you are getting a warning)  and ignoring it (since you might miss other important exceptions consider checking the division first. I.e.

```
$divisor = 0;
$num = 100;
if($divisor){
    $result=100/0;
}else{
    $result = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)  to throw the PHP warnings/errors as exceptions:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    if ( 'Division by zero' == $errstr) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    }
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try
{
    $result=100/0;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $result=0;
}

echo $result;
```